# Cannot login to Mautic Dashboard

Tags: php, symfony, sessionid, mautic, server-migration

I am currently using Mautic 3.0.0, PHP 7.3 and MySQL 10.4.13.

My problem is that when I go to the Mautic login page, enter my username and password and click on “login”, the webpage only refreshes and there isn’t a redirection to the Dashboard. I am sure that my authentication credentials are correct.

I should also mention that I recently migrated my website from a cPanel to a DirectAdmin shared server, but I was able to login successfully even after the migration.

These errors are showing in the log file:

```
mautic.WARNING: PHP Warning - SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/sess_…, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) - in file ~/mautic/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/StrictSessionHandler.php - at line 48 {“sessionId”:"…"} []

mautic.WARNING: PHP Warning - SessionHandler::write(): open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/sess_…, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) - in file ~/mautic/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/StrictSessionHandler.php - at line 64 [] []

mautic.WARNING: PHP Warning - session_write_close(): Failed to write session data with “Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\StrictSessionHandler” handler - in file ~/mautic/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php - at line 268 [] []
```

I tried to login in different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge and IE) and cleared the cache and website’s data, but it didn't fix the issue.

What should I do to have this fixed?

Comment: check your host permissions, looks like the php server cant crete your session file!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running PHP5.6. Not PHP7.3. "`ea-php56`"

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/sess_…, O_RDWR
```

Make sure your host configuration is set to use PHP7.3 and make sure the correct sessions path is writeable by PHP7.3. PHP5.6 may be in a group separate from PHP7.3 and it looks like it's trying to write to 5.6 path.

Comment: The PHP version of the old cPanel server was 5.6 and it is 7.3 in the DirectAdmin server, so I think that Symfony's session handler still uses the old path (which -I guess- no longer exists after moving my website). How do I change the session path?

Comment: You need to change the configuration for the specific Website Settings. The server may support PHP 7.3, but typically you have to configure each Website to use a specific PHP version.

consider this How to for more information: https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/change-php-version-and-modify-php-settings-with-cpanel/

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whGZm8w01T4&ab_channel=DomainRacer